# name tag isn't being recognized in my javascript from html.beginform

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, razor

I have some javascript here

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Autocomplete variables
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
var searchform = document.getElementById('form1');
var place;
```

I have created a form in my html that looks like this and everything works fine

```
<form action="javascript:void(0);" name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="location" class="textbox" id="location" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="submit" />
</form>
```

but when I change the form to use a HTML.BeginForm like this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", FormMethod.Get, new { name = "form1", id = "form1" }))
{
    <p>
        @*@Html.TextBox("Location", null, new {id = "location"})*@
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" value="" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value='Submit' type="submit"/>
    </p>
}
```

the javascript below doesn't recognize the form1 name and there is a blue line underneath it with a message that says "cannot resolve id 'form1'"

```
var searchform = document.getElementById('form1');
```

Comment: Ignore the blue line, it should work fine.

Comment: I have duplicated your code in my project and can't reproduce it. Are you by any chance using an older version of IE? (IE has a problem with form elements having a matching `id` and `name` attribute)

Comment: I'm using whatever version comes with Windows 8.1, but it's not a IE issue its a VS issue with the razor syntax I think? When I swap out the two versions of the form's I've created and shown above one works fine the other breaks. It's something that has to do with my action. When I swap out javascript:void(0) with the "Results" action it works.

Comment: Agreed, but just wanted to make sure you understand that your code may fail if a user is using IE7 due to the `id` and `name` attributes having the same value.